# Find equivalent interest rate for cash advance fee + promo rate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, financial, differential-equations

I take a cash advance of 'amount' from my credit card, paying an 
up-front 'fee' (given as a percentage), with a promotional rate 'int' 
for time 'len'. I must pay at least 'min'% of the owed amount monthly.

I put 'amount' into an investment account earning 'p'% interest, and 
also make the monthly payments from this account.

Question: for what value of 'p' will I break even after time 'len'?

Here's how I set it up in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[{ 

(* I start off owing amount plus the fee *) 
owed[0] == amount*(1+fee), 

(* The amount I owe increases due to credit card interest, 
   but decreases due to monthly payments *) 
owed'[t] == int*owed[t]-min*12*owed[t], 

(* I start off having amount *) 
have[0] == amount, 

(* The amount I have increases due to investment interest, 
   but decreases due to monthly payments *) 
have'[t] == p*have[t]-min*12*owed[t], 

(* After len, I want to break even *) 
owed[len] == have[len] 
}, 
{owed[t], have[t]}, {t}]
```

Mathematica returns "DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general 
solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution", 
which is actually reasonable: there's only one value of 'p' that will 
yield a solution for the differential equations above.

How do I coerce Mathematica into finding this value?

I tried solving for owed[t], then substituting owed[t] into have[t], 
and then solving owed[len] == have[len], but this yield a similar 
error. Running Reduce on "owed[len] == have[len]" yielded something 
complex and ugly.

Comment: So far, my plan to coerce people into giving me better answers has not met with wide success ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation:

```
owed'[t] == int owed[t]-min 12 owed[t]
```

if both **int** and **min** are constants, is just a exponential function. With the initial condition

```
owed[0] == amount*(1 + fee)
```

gives

```
owed[t_] := amount E^((int - 12 min) t) (1 + fee)
```

And that's the solution for owed[t]

Now for have[t] you may use:

```
DSolve[{
  have'[t] == p*have[t] - min*12*owed[t],
  have[len] == owed[len]},
 {have[t]}, {t}]
```

That gives you the expression for have[t] that meets your break even condition.

For obtaining the value of p, you must use the last equation:

```
 have[0] == amount
```

or, after replacing have[0] for it's value:

```
(amount E^(-len p) (1 + fee) (12 E^(len p) min + 
   E^(len (int - 12 min)) (-int + p)))/(-int + 12 min + p) == amount
```

This last equation seems not easily solved for p. I tried a few things (not too much, certainly) and it resists strong.

But ... given numerical values for the rest of the parameters is trivially solved by any numerical method (I guess)

Comment: OK, so the crux here is that you can't put 'have[0] == amount' inside of DSolve, because there's no general solution. However, if you compute the general solution and then do 'have[0] == amount', you're fine.

Comment: @barrycarter Well, I'm not sure why it doesn't work with "all inside", just tried to find a way out ...

Comment: Yes, thanks! I was just trying to figure out what I did wrong, and that appears to be it.